# Heroku dynos crashing

Tags: python, heroku

I readed a lot of questions here in stackoverflow, but I cannot solve my problem.

I have a simples python script (Only a print('Hello World')) and I'm sending it to Heroku, my files are:

Procfile: (I believe the problem is here)

```
web: python index.py
```

heroku logs --tail

```
2020-05-06T16:06:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user <myemail>
2020-05-06T16:07:00.948412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-06T16:07:00.572714+00:00 app[api]: Release v11 created by user <myemail>
2020-05-06T16:07:00.572714+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4053de7f by user <myemail>
2020-05-06T16:07:07.099124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-06T16:07:07.103524+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-05-06T16:07:07.002972+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello World
2020-05-06T16:07:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-06T16:07:13.797877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-05-06T16:07:13.619779+00:00 app[web.1]: Hello World
```

heroku ts

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 550h 0m (100%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): python index.py (1)
web.1: crashed 2020/05/06 13:07:13 -0300 (~ 4m ago)
```

How we can see, the "Hello World" in log shows that the script runs when I send it to server. But after it, the dyno crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case of Web dyno the application must bind to the port provided by Heroku and defined in the $PORT env variable, where it will receive the incoming requests.

If you need to HTTP traffic try to create a `worker` node

For example to create a simple Flask app which can receive requests:

```
from flask import Flask
import os
import logging

try:
  app = Flask(__name__)
except Exception as e:
  logging.exception("Error at startup")

@app.route('/test')
def test():
 logging.info('/test')
 return "test Ok"

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=False, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')
```

Port is set using $PORT on Heroku while locally defaults to 5000

Comment: I believe the problem is with the port. Sorry, but... How can I do it?

Comment: If you want to create a web dyno I would suggest to build a very simple Flask application, where you can set the port `app.run(debug=True, port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)), host='0.0.0.0')`. Define some routes so you can call them from the browser

Comment: Edited the answer to add a simple example, hope it is clear

Comment: I didn't know what is Flask and how to use it. But your answer helped me to know what to search at google. Thank you

Comment: No problem! Flask is a Python micro web framework,  but you have other options of course